# JBPM 5 ProcessInstanceInfo && EventTypes

Tags: drools, jbpm

What is the use of EventTypes table in JBPM 5?

Does it store the name of the possible signal's the process-instance can accept ?

Or does it store the events that has occured on the process-instance ?

I can see that the entries in this EventTypes table keeps changing in the process-instance's execution for an instance-id.

Answer (score 1):

The EventTypes table contains all the (external) signals that a specific process instance is (possibly) waiting for.  This table in used to determine which process instances should be loaded if a signal is detected.

Kris

Comment: Why does the entries in the eventtypes table keep changing? The entries in this table is not consistent. It doesn't have expected signals from my process definition and my signal to that instance fails.kindly refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320120/jbpm-catch-intermediate-signal-fails-sometime/15351716?noredirect=1#15351716

Comment: And sometimes the signal name in the EventTypes table is just empty strings.Can this be a problem with process-definition (bpmn) ?